# Notification in Android before the specified date

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications, alarmmanager

I created a notification assume "My Exams".

i want to show reminder notification 3 days before the set date

i'm storing date in database want to compare it with current date and display notification

Any Help will be appreciated

Thank You...

Comment: its working like this for me: when i select values from datepicker like    int day = picker.getDayOfMonth();
     int month = picker.getMonth();
     int year = picker.getYear(); i;ll take one int variable with value 3 and i';; subtract the day pass value to calender like this Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         c.set(year, month, day); and call notification it works fine but now the problem is if my date is 1st of the month tht subtract logic wont work any help will be appreciated:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate a date that is 3 days prior to a specific date try this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year, month, day); // Set the calendar NOTE: this will not change the hour, minute, second
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -3); // Roll the calendar back 3 days
```

Comment: that what i am looking for, tx